# Bootstrap form alignment not proper

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: The form]

The following code is written for a form but the from is not properly aligned in bootstrap.
Although i have divided the form in rows but what i do not understand is that how is the first column not properly aligned. I tried a lot of things but could not figure it out.
Pl help me make this alright!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<form >
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Roll number:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2  ">School code:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Year Of Passing:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" >
</div></div></div>

<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">First Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Middle Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Last Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" >
</div></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Father's First name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Father's Middle name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group ">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Father's Last name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div>

</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Mother's First name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Mother's Middle name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Mother's Last name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Gender:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><select class="form-control" >
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>

</select>
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Mobile Number:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Aadhar Number:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Email:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="email" class="form-control " >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">DOB:</label>

<div class="col-sm-1"><select class="form-control " >
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>17</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
<option>23</option>
<option>24</option>
<option>25</option>
<option>26</option>
<option>27</option>
<option>28</option>
<option>29</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>31</option>

</select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><select class="form-control " >
<option>Jan</option>
<option>Feb</option>
<option>Mar</option>
<option>Apr</option>
<option>May</option>
<option>Jun</option>
<option>Jul</option>
<option>Aug</option>
<option>Sep</option>
<option>Oct</option>
<option>Nov</option>
<option>Dec</option>

</select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2"><select class="form-control " >
<option>2000</option>
<option>2001</option>
<option>2002</option>
<option>2003</option>
<option>2004</option>
<option>2005</option>
<option>2006</option>
<option>2007</option>
<option>2008</option>
<option>2009</option>
<option>2010</option>
<option>2011</option>
<option>2012</option>
<option>2013</option>
<option>2014</option>
<option>2015</option>
<option>2016</option>    
</select>
</div></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Religion:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div>



<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Age:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 ">Category:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control " >
</div></div></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this while working with django-bootstrap3, using the `{% bootstrap_field form.attribute %}` template tag.

The problem is that you're using too many form-group tags.  You only need one surrounding the entire group of form inputs.  After removing the tags, and deleting the now-superfluous divs, I get the following code, which renders without the misalignment of the second and following columns compared to the first:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form >
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 ">Roll number:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" ></div>
                        <label class="col-sm-2  ">School code:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control " ></div>
                        <label class="col-sm-2 ">Year Of Passing:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 ">First Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control " ></div>
                        <label class="col-sm-2 ">Middle Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" ></div>
                        <label class="col-sm-2 ">Last Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" ></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This looks right on the webserver setup I am using.

I ran into this issue because I was grouping django-bootstrap `{% bootstrap_field form.attribute %}`tags into rows, but the default behavior is to create a div with the form-group tag for each form field.  I overrode it using `form_group_class=""` Example:

```
{% bootstrap_field form.jobNum form_group_class="" field_class="col-md-3" label_class="col-md-2 text-right" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you use ***row*** class is not correct. It should be  -

```
row > col-xs-4 > form-group > col-sm-6


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-6">Roll number:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-6">School code:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control ">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-6">Year Of Passing:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle with **form-horizontal** and **control-label**.

https://jsfiddle.net/g6ryga19/

Comment: There's still an alignment issue with the second and third input fields being lower than the first one.

Comment: You will have to apply all row classes to same format. `row > col-xs-4 > form-group > col-sm-6`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your layout I would recommend adding `form-horizontal` to your `<form>` and adding `control-label` to all of your labels.  In addition, I would re-organize your form into 3 separate columns like so:

```
<form class="form form-horizontal">

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Roll number:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" ></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">School code:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control " ></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Year Of Passing:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" ></div>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Note: `form-horizontal` changes the behavior of `form-group` and causes it to mimic `row` so you can avoid an additional `<div>`

Comment: In Bootstrap, **col-xx-xx** should always be inside **row** or **form-group**. Main reason is **col-xx-xx** has 15px padding left and right, so without row or form-group it won't flash with left and right borders.